# Hibernate effects of createSQLQuery on cache

Tags: sql, hibernate, caching

By executing the follwoing function:

```
public void deleteByEntryId(long id)
{
    super.getSession().createSQLQuery("DELETE FROM guest WHERE entry_fk = " + id).executeUpdate();
}
```

will the cache of Hibernate be aware / notified of the deletion of the Guest objects?

- The super class is Spring's Hibernate Template which offers the method `getSession()` and many others
- createSQLQuery(...)` is a function of Hibernate.

(I am asking as depeding on whether I am deleting by object or by SQLquery I get a StaleState or a OtimistickLockException further on in my test.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, it won't. Even HQL update and delete queries don't affect in-memory state.

Answer (score 2):

To invalidate Guests table cache you need to add "addSynchronizedEntityClass" invocation:

```
public void deleteByEntryId(long id)
{
  super.getSession()
         .createSQLQuery("DELETE FROM guest WHERE entry_fk = " + id)
         .addSynchronizedEntityClass(Guest.class)
         .executeUpdate();
}
```